# ejabberd command not found, non-existent ejabberd.cfg

Tags: ejabberd

I inherited an ejabberd installation from a previous employee. Basic commands return

> Error command 'xxxx' not known

The doc refers to /etc/ejabberd.cfg, which does not exist on the server. `/opt/ejabberd-15.03/conf/ejabberd.yml` seems to contain all pertinent configs, such as LDAP and ssl certificate locations.

Everything seems to be running fine for the users, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. Here are some samples:

```
[root@jabber bin]# pwd
/opt/ejabberd-15.03/bin
[root@jabber bin]# ./ejabberdctl create_room SteveTest conference.localhost localhost
```

> Error: command "create_room" not known.

```
[root@jabber bin]# ./ejabberdctl muc_online_rooms global
```

> Error: command "muc_online_rooms" not known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Configuration file

> The doc refers to /etc/ejabberd.cfg, which does not exist on the server. /opt/ejabberd-15.03/conf/ejabberd.yml seems to contain all pertinent configs, such as LDAP and ssl certificate locations.

The location of the configuration file is specific to the way `ejabberd` got installed, so having it in `/opt/ejabberd-15.03/conf/` should be fine.

The reason for `ejabberd.cfg` vs. `ejabberd.yml` is that [ejabberd 13.10 introduced YAML as configuration file format](https://blog.process-one.net/switch-ejabberd-configuration-to-yaml/) (`ejabberd.yml`) and deprecated the previously used Erlang terms based one (`ejabberd.cfg`). From [their documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#legacy-configuration-file):

> In previous ejabberd version the configuration file should be written in Erlang terms. The format is still supported, but it is highly recommended to convert it to the new YAML […]

### ejabberdctl

When you run `ejabberdctl` without any arguments it should show you all supported commands.

The ones you tried (`create_room` and `muc_online_rooms`) shouldn't be in the list, as they are [part of the `mod_muc_admin` module](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/d87151aee6b07c04f7659336fa1fada4d274f2d8/src/mod_muc_admin.erl), which got [introduced with ejabberd 15.04](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-15-04/), but you appear to be running the older ejabberd 15.03.

To get these commands you can either upgrade `ejabberd`, which would be the recommended way, or fetch the `mod_muc_admin` module from the [`ejabberd-contrib`](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib) repository, which contains third-party ejabberd modules. `mod_muc_admin` was part of this repository before it became directly included into ejabberd. Here is a link to the last revision of `ejabberd-contrib` which still contains the module: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/e5336f/mod_muc_admin